# How to access iPhone's general accessibility settings

Tags: iphone, settings, accessibility

I need to access the iPhone's general accessibility settings; I need to know whether the user has turn on features such as "Speak Auto-text" or "White on Black" and respond to that programatically. I don't need to change the values, only read them. Also, if there's a way of defining (for my app) to ignore them (and set the corresponding support programatically) - that would be a good solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  I suspect this is by design.

Answer (score 3):

what about UIKit accessibility methods?

```
Accessibility
UIAccessibilityPostNotification
UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning
UIAccessibilityIsClosedCaptioningEnabled
UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled
UIAccessibilityIsInvertColorsEnabled
UIAccessibilityIsMonoAudioEnabled
UIAccessibilityZoomFocusChanged
UIAccessibilityRegisterGestureConflictWithZoom
```

Comment: These didn't exist when the question was asked in 2010.