# How to tell iOS that Speak Selection should be turned on

Tags: objective-c, settings, accessibility, ios5.1

Is there a way to tell iOS that the Accessibility feature Speak Selection should be turned on?
I thought there might be a way similar to location service where as soon as you start using it, iOS asks the user to turn it on.

I know that Speak Selection is used in a more 'passive' way, but perhaps someone knows the trick, especially now that you cannot open the Settings app using "prefs:root..." anymore since iOS 5.1

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [How to access iPhone's general accessibility settings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2175624/62576), where the accepted answer is "You can't. I suspect this is by design.".

Comment: Not really - as I wrote above, when you start using LocationService iOS does the job for you and prompt the user to turn it on. You don't need to open settings app programmatically in this case.