# Detecting iOS/Android native accesibility features via Adobe AIR

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

I'm looking to implement some custom functionality in my Adobe AIR mobile app, for users requiring accessibility features. I understand that there's little to no crossover between native accessibility features and the AIR runtime, and this is actually fine - what I'd like to do is simply detect whether or not the user has anything activated on their device, and if so change the app's behaviour a little. I don't need to set anything. I'm particularly interested in things like voiceover etc.

I know that native extensions can be used to access a bunch of system-level information, and I know that there are calls that can be made (for example) on iOS to detect if certain features are currently switched on - [How to access iPhone's general accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175624/how-to-access-iphones-general-accessibility-settings). However I can't seem to find much reliable documentation on how I would access this information from a native extension or otherwise.

Is there a reliable way for me to detect this sort of thing on both iOS and Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it turns out that this is certainly possible on both iOS and Android. I ended up writing a native extension to accomplish this, in case anyone sees this thread as a reference.

I can't post the whole thing yet, but figuring out if the user is using accessibility features is fairly straightforward on both iOS (just do a check for UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning)

And on Android:
[How to access iPhone's general accessibility settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175624/how-to-access-iphones-general-accessibility-settings)